# What do these dotted half notes mean?

Tags: piano, notation

I've recently started playing the piano and I've been curious about a music piece. This is the only thing i haven't been able to figure out why it's there. Would appreciate some help, thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm new to this format and probably didn't know what question to ask, thank you!

Comment: as you know now the answer, maybe you could ask something different about these bars: " is the notation of the  chords  of the intro correct? and what is the harmonic  meaning?"

Comment: Which piece is this?

Comment: This is "Nocturne" from Katawa Shoujo by Nicol Armarfi (Sebastien Skaf)

Link: http://nicol.chendo.net/music/KS%20Piano/Nocturne/

Comment: You have multiple voices and the longer notes should be held while the others are played.